# Complicated text replace per line in PHP string

Tags: php, xml

I have a string that contains lines like the following

```
<category id blabla>2</category>
...
<name>bloblo</name>
<category id blabla>35</category>
```

and an array like this

```
[2] => Shoes
[35] => T-Shirts
```

I want to scan every line that contains the word "category", putting the number between tags in a variable, so i can map it with the array and then replace the number with the name of the category.

I am trying to find an effective way to do this, as the string contains almost 12k lines.
Tried with preg_split in foreach, but i am afraid the script crashes and i get no output (will try again tomorrow).
Puting the XML code in simplexml_load_string neither seems to work (it works with smaller strings, but not with this one).

Comment: "Puting the XML code in simplexml_load_string neither seems to work" - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JackFleeting Probably it crashes because of huge size. I didn't bothered yet to find the reason, and also i don't prefer to make it an array and then back again an xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $xml = str_replace(">" . $key . "</category>", ">" . $value . "</category>");
    }
```

Where $array is your mapping array and $xml is your xml. However this may not work for situations where you have spaces arround the value from the category tag, as they would need to be mapped separately. But if your xml respects the same format everywhere it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

or this:

```
$str = '
<category id blabla>2</category>
...
<name>bloblo</name>
<category id blabla>35</category>';

$lines = explode("\n", $str);
$result = [];
$replacements = [
    '2' => "Shoes",
    '35' => "T-Shirts",
];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strrpos(trim($line), '<category') === 0) {
        $a = explode(">", $line, 2);
        $b = explode("<", $a[1], 2);
        $num = $b[0];
        $replaced = $replacements[$num];
        $line = ($a[0] . ">" . $replaced . "<" . $b[1]);
    }
    $result[] = $line;
}

$final = implode("\n", $result);
echo "<xmp>" . $final . "</xmp>";
```

output:

```
<category id blabla>Shoes</category>
...
<name>bloblo</name>
<category id blabla>T-Shirts</category>
```

Comment: Can you explain the code into strrpos?
I can't make it work. Doesn't replace anything.

Comment: The code works. I don't replace but re-construct the string from 2 parts. As for `strrpos` is a common function for dealing with strings.

Comment: the code obviously doesn't work when xml has random spaces in the start of every line

Comment: Yes I should have trim the string. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult in DOM:

```php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<data>
    <category id="blabla">2</category>
    <name>bloblo</name>
    <category id="blabla">35</category>
</data>
XML;

$map = [    
    '2' => "Shoes",
    '35' => "T-Shirts",
];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate over any category element
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//category') as $category) {
    // read id and cleanup whitespaces
    $categoryId = trim($category->textContent);
    // write mapped value
    $category->textContent = $map[$categoryId] ?? $categoryId;
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```